# Проблема с ajax подгрузкой при прокрутке, как решить?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

В последнее время много вопросов, ну та ладно. К сути: смог  сделать подгрузку при прокрутке, но вот 2 проблемы:надо подгружать при прокрутке блока, а не всей страницы. 2.Загружается всё и сразу, и проблема тут не в обработчике, а в аяксе. После того как ты первый раз догружаешь... Блок увеличивается, он считает это прокруткой, и повторно его увеличивает( мне надо постепенно подгружать по  25 записей при достижение 80% скролла блока( новые сообщения снизу, сверху старое(подобие вк диалога) 
аjax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var inProgress = false;
var startFrom = 25;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() && !inProgress) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "pages/blocks/message/relevate.php?set=<?echo $_GET['set'];?>",
            method: 'POST',
            data: {"startFrom" : startFrom},
            beforeSend: function() {

               inProgress = true;}

            }).done(function(data){
               data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               if (data.length > 0) {
          $.each(data, function(index, data){
               $(".logick").prepend("<p><b><div class='gg'>" + data.message + "</b><br />" + data.id + "</div></p>");
            });
                    inProgress = false;
            startFrom += 25;
            }});
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Я сомневаюсь, что тут может понадобится обработчик, но вот он

```
$startFrom = $_POST['startFrom'];
$sm  = R::find( 'messages', ' dialog = ? ',array($_GET['set']));
$result = count($sm);
$sm = array_reverse($sm);
if($result > 25){

  if($startFrom > 25){
    $startFrom = $startFrom;
  }else{
    $startFrom = "25";
  }
$fr =  array_slice($sm, $startFrom, 25);
$articles = array();
foreach ($fr as $fr) {
$articles[] = $fr;
}
echo json_encode($articles);
}
```

Comment: Собсна в чем вопрос, что вам не понятно? Вроде-ж все понимаете, задачу описали? или вы хотите чтоб написали за вас?

Comment: я плохо понимаю, как это решить :D